# How to use Fuzzy Search to search ListBox items in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have a problem with `ListBox` in `asp.net`

How to use fuzzy search to search `ListBox items` ?

I just have partial key words , and want to find items use partial key words.

How to do that?

or I only could use `For` or `Foreach` loop to find items?

Comment: You can use lambda Expression for search.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta I dont know how to use Lambda Eexpression X-( , but thank you to notify me , I will try hard